# How to make indent-relative not indent when the buffer is empty?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a function that overrides the behavior of indenting on return to be a simple block indent. The problem is that both indent-relative and indent-relative-maybe will indent when the buffer is empty.

When I create a buffer I may want a few blank lines at the top and these functions cause the cursor to indent when there is no previous block to be indented to.

How can I fix this?

```
(defun my-enter ()
  "Inserts a newline character then indents the new line just like the previous line"
  (interactive)
  (newline)
  (indent-relative-maybe))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're including "contains newlines" in your definition of "empty", you could apply the following constraint:

```el
(unless (looking-back "\\`\n*")
  (indent-relative-maybe))
```